# autocomplete in TeXnicCenter does not work when biblatex is used

Tags: biblatex, texniccenter, auto-completion

I'm working with TeXnicCenter and I set a up a project file and created my output pdf file and bibliography using biblatex. Everything works well, the document looks the way it should...and now comes the but: I can't get the autocomplete for the \cite{} (any citation command actually) working. I don't even see the references in the reference tab (stable version TeXnicCenter) or in the Literature window (Alpha version). This is a bit annoying, since I have a huge list of references in my .bib file.
Does anyone know, how to fix that? Maybe a note, I have just recently switched to biblatex and before I started using it, I could see the references and the autocomplete function was working.

Here is a minimal example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}  
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[american]{babel}  
\usepackage{filecontents}    
\usepackage{csquotes}        

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,%  
natbib=true,      % enable natbib macros  
bibencoding=ascii,   
url=false,  
sorting=nyt,  
uniquename=false,  
firstinits=true, % use initials as first names  
uniquelist=false,   
dashed=false,     % do not use a dash instead of author name in case of several publications  
maxnames=99,     % in the bibliography show all names   
maxcitenames=2,   % in the text use et al. for more than 2   
backref=true,     % have backrefs in the bibliography   
backend=bibtex8,   
refsegment=section]{biblatex}   

\addbibresource{PhDall.bib}   

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
\usepackage{setspace}   
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}  
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[figure,table]{hypcap}  

%-------Main-Document-Body---------  

\begin{document}  

\chapter{test}\label{testchapter}  

lets see if this works: \parencite{albergel_evaluation_2012} and \parencite{maltese_event_2010}  

\printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

And the bibliography -which I get from zotero (coding Western - ISO8859-1) -looks like that:

```
@inproceedings{maltese_event_2010,  
    title = {Event detection of hydrological processes with passive L-band data from {SMOS}},  
    volume = {7824},   
    shorttitle = {Event detection of hydrological processes with passive L-band data from {SMOS}},  
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1117/12.865074},  
    doi = {10.1117/12.865074},  
    booktitle = {{SPIE}},  
    publisher = {{SPIE}},  
    author = {Maltese, Antonio and Al Bitar, Ahmad and Jacquette, Elsa and Kerr, Yann and Mialon, Arnaud and Cabot, Francoise and Quesney, Arnaud and Merlin, Olivier and Richaume, Phillipe},  
    year = {2010},  
    pages = {78240J}  
},

@article{albergel_evaluation_2012,  
title = {Evaluation of remotely sensed and modelled soil moisture products using global ground-based in situ observations},  
    volume = {118},  
    shorttitle = {Evaluation of remotely sensed and modelled soil moisture products using global ground-based in situ observations},  
    url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425711004147},  
doi = {10.1016/j.rse.2011.11.017},  
journal = {Remote Sensing of Environment},  
author = {Albergel, Clement and de Rosnay, Patricia and Gruhier, Claire and {Mu\~{n}oz-Sabater}, Joaquin and Hasenauer, Stefan and Isaksen, Lars and Kerr, Yann and Wagner, Wolfgang},  
year = {2012},  
pages = {215--226}  
}
```

Any suggestions where I interfer with the autocomplete option??
Thanks

Comment: May be try using \bibliography{example.bib} before \end{document} for autocompletion and comment it before you run the pdflatex

Comment: Great! That really does the trick! Amazing...so easy! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 7):

By adding these three lines

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}{\addbibresource{literatur.bib}}{\bibliography{literatur}}
\makeatother
```

instead of just

```
\addbibresource{}
```

TeXnicCenter believes you are using

```
\bibliography{}
```

and integrates it accordingly into the GUI and for autocomplete.

This solution has the beauty of working with both `biblatex` (+biber) and classic BibTeX and does not need any uncommenting before compiling.

Comment: Sorry for commenting on this, but could you explain this a little bit more? This worked beautifully for me.

Comment: @masfenix, what exactly needs clarification? It's checking whether `biblatex` package is loaded and then uses `\addbibresource`, otherwise the classic `\bibliography` command. Since TeXnicCenter does not check for `if` clauses, it just assumes `\bibliography` has been used and binds it into the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

As mention in the comment by [texlearner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15717/texlearner), here the trick:

> Try using `\bibliography{example.bib}` before `\end{document}` for
>   autocompletion and comment it before you run the pdflatex